# DocuSign API ERROR generic error on example provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

**Hello and good night,**

I have been instructed in the DocuSign website that stackoverflow is a correct path to create questions for any doubts in general. I have been trying to run a test on DocuSign, using a recently created demo account but i have been having some troubles with the example. I have chosen Ruby due to my company using Ruby for the current project at the moment, so i could not run any other examples in other languages i would be more familiar with. 
My current error after running the application and following the instructions is a generic error called API ERROR. I tried to print the variable but had no success. When the application is running i have 3 links to each separated function (corresponding to a file)

The link to the Ruby example by DocuSign is here: https://github.com/docusign/qs-ruby

Where can i see the specific Ruby / Ruby on Rails error?

I am running Windows 10 with Ruby 2.5.8.

[image]
[image]

Comment: We also have https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant for Ruby

Comment: Have you obtained an auth token?

Comment: I got the Token generated on the Website on my account, on this link:
https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator
Is that correct? The Auth Code Grant you chose posted, is to generate a Token programaticly ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a result of obsolete code that has been removed and replaced by new code that can be found at https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-ruby.

I also recommend that anyone that wants to get started with Ruby and the DocuSign APIs should use the [DocuSign Quickstart on the Developer Center.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) This way you get everything that has to do with authentication already set up and configured for you automatically and saves you the need to do it yourself.